# How can we change the direction of the Shadow filter

Tags: node-editor

I am trying to create a cavity map from a normal map. In Photoshop, we can set an angle for the emboss, the red channel of need to be emboss to the right and the green to the top. In Blender, I guess we must add nodes to edit the shadow filter. Also, when I use the shadow filter i don't get a flat color i still get a variation of gray.

The normal map and goal on this [link](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?383624-Dark-Blender-(Official-Thread)-optimized-for-sculpting-and-game-asset-creation&p=3056216&viewfull=1#post3056216). The tutorial in Photoshop can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MItPuQz3qLg).